# Shutdown 3G modem

Tags: modem, unmount

How can I shutdown 3G modem (ttyUSB0)?
Because even when I shutting down I see the lights on it. 
So maybe my question is : how I can eject 3G modem.
Or how I can unmount it.

Help me to find out in my question and in the solution.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/567580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you unmount or eject it the Modem will still have lights on as the USB will still feed it power so nothing to worry about Ubuntu won't use it unless it's all connected so when you shut it down Ubuntu will no longer use it until next reboot or if you pull it out and reconnect